# Build Multi Azure DevOps Pull Request in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins

My git repository is Azure Dev-Ops and use Jenkins for continuous integration build and I use tfs Plugin for Jenkins.
My code has 6 branches:

master, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5

When i want pull request `test1 to master`(for example pull request number is 100) and `test5 to test4`(for example pull request number is 101) Jenkins only build pull request for number 100 don't build pull request number 101.

after several time when i want build for pull request `test3 to test2`(for example pull request number is 102) Jenkins again build for pull request number 100.

I don't know What's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Understood in Service hooks Azure Dev-ops for Jenkins service
we have 2 trigger that are

1. Trigger generic build
2. Trigger Git Build

unfortunately in official document for tfs `https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin` don't say that `Trigger generic build` use for when we have only a branch and `Trigger Git Build` use for when we have multi branch on pipeline Jenkins.
So I change my trigger from `Trigger generic build` to `Trigger Git Build`

Comment: Hi! how did you were able to implement azure devops PRs from the jenkins side? do you have any guide for that? , I couldn't use the git-scm plugin to discover azure devops PRs and tfs-plugin is not maintained any more

Comment: Hi for integrate azure devops pull request and push on specific branch to Jenkins need two plugin. git plugin and tfs plugin.
you can download and install jenkins tfs plugin from this blow:
```
https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases
```
after that you can set service hooks in azure devops

Comment: Hi, I already have both of the plugins, and also the service hooks in azure devops which is working for the branchers, but I can't find a way to enable it for PRs

Comment: What is your trigger set in your service hooks on azure devops??
pipeline or multibranch ???

Comment: I have multibranch, do you use the tfs plugin to discrover branches/tags/PRs or the git plugin?

Comment: Based on this document of multibranch Pipeline
```https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/```
multibranch pipeline dont support tfs but in my company i integerate pull request azure devops and Jenkins with Pipeline and Jenkins send status of build pull request to azure devops.

Comment: @dsaydon can you implement pipeline multibranch with and tfs plugin Azure Dev Ops??

Comment: I implemented it, but it didn't work for me as expected