# Choose Jenkinsfile of target branch or source branch while doing Pull Request

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

My git repository is Azure DevOps and uses Jenkins for continuous integration build and I use TFS Plugin for Jenkins.

For example I have 50 branches, most of them have a different Jenkins file. While I request pull on Azure DevOps, I want to be able to choose the Jenkins file of source branch or target branch.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. If you have 50 branches, and try to build one of them, why would you want to use a different Jenkinsfile than the one in that exact branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for your Responses but I Understood IT's related to Developer role that should update his Jenkins file on his branch  Of course I Understood something is related to kind of Trigger
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641090/build-multi-azure-devops-pull-request-in-jenkins`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to choose the Jenkins file of source branch or target branch.

You could select the `Pull request merge attempted` in the type of Trigger event:

[image]

Which have an optional `Target branch`. We could select the target branch for the Azure devops Azure DevOps.